# How to determine correct voltage input on a multivoltage power-transformer?

Tags: transformer, vacuum-tube

I have an old tube radio that has multiple mains selector - 240V; 220V; 127V; 110V. The back-plate where the description how to set the selector correctly has gone missing. There are no markings anywhere that may give me additional clue. So how can I find the right position of the selector using tester.
I have measured the resistance of the primary coils as follows 21 OHM; 17 OHM; 11 OHM; 7 OHM

Comment: Which ever has the highest resistance I'd expect to be the 240 input.

Comment: If you can identify a 6,3V secondary, try to measure its output with 10V on each primary and you should be able to identify their transformation ratio.

Comment: +1 for Andy. Since you already know or reasonably suspect what voltages it is built for, you pretty much just put them in order. That being said, if there is any doubt at all as to what winding is the low voltage side, be very careful with any kind of live testing; jacking 10 volts into the low side would be predictably dangerous on the high side.

Answer (score 1):

First method, the safest one: check it on schematics, manual or photos in net.

Second method (commentators were close but not exactly): **measure the resistance between power plug pins, *NOT every single primary coil*, in every position of selector**. Measuring resistance or voltage on every single coil gives us no meaningful information if we don't know how selector connects coils (look at method one).

In nearly every old radio which I know (and other equipment) voltage selector doesn't switch between single coils. Coils are connected in series (one winding with several taps) and selector just connect one line of main supply to one of these taps. For example if we have a 220V/110V selector the transformer should have two identical primary coils (both rated for 110V), at "110V" mains is connected to only one coil (second one is left floating), and at "220V" coils are connected in series and powered from the start of first coil to the end of second coil. I've attached a part of schematic of old Swedish AGA radio - there is one winding with five taps and switch to select them.

[image: old radio main transfomer]